# Throwing copyable class deriving from noncopyable

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a framework which defines exception as a non-copyable class, from which we derived a copyable class (defining a copy constructor calling a non-copy base class constructor)

This works under g++, but not under MSVC 2013.

The following code will reproduce the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#if defined _MSC_VER
#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCTION__
#endif

class u {
  u(const u&) = delete;
  const u& operator=(const u&) = delete;/* the library we use defines it as const u& */
public:
  u() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "def" << endl; }
protected:
  explicit u(int i) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "int: " << i << endl; }
};

class e : public u {
public:
  e() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "def" << endl; }
  e(const e& _e) : u(1) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "cpy" << endl; }
  e& operator=(const e& _e) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; return *this; }
};

int foo() {
  e _e;
  throw _e;

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  try {
    foo();
  } catch(const e& _e) {
    cout << "in catch e" << endl;
  } catch(...) {
    cout << "in catch..." << endl;
  }
#if defined _MSC_VER
  cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
  cin.get();
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

MSVC complains about `Error 1   error C2280: 'u::u(const u &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function` at the end of function foo().

g++ and clang both compile the code, and they don't use the copy constructor at all (the e object is moved), but neither will compile if `e` isn't copy-constructable.

EDIT: I've edited the code to force a copy.

BTW, if the `u` copy functions are not deleted (nor defined, pre-c++11 non-copyable), MSVC fails at link phase during `u::u(const u&)` lookup. (unresolved external)

Is there a flaw in my code, or is this bug in MSVC?

Comment: This works on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/, so I'm going to go with a MSVC bug that's been fixed in MSVC 2015.

Comment: seems like msvc bug, not invoke move constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715468/can-i-throw-a-unique-ptr

Comment: My first guess would be that when throwing an `e` object, you might catch it as `u`. (Not as a reference to a `u`.) In that case you would need the copy ctor of `u`. Maybe gcc and clang put that copy invocation near the catch clause (which does not exist here), but MSVC might want to put it after the `throw` statement. It wouldn't be invoked, but the compiler references it.

Comment: `u` is an exception class that effectively disables the C++11 exception handling machinery. The `const u&` return for the copy constructors shouts loudly and clearly that this was not intentionally: that the developers were incompetent. The easy solution is therefore: *ditch that library*. That said, MSVC has a number of bugs related to constructors, but while it's not legally within its rights here its morally right, because you've told it that an `e` *IS-A* `u` with no data added. Accordingly, making the inheritance non-`public` makes the code compile, but rather defeats the purpose. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `e` and `u` both have user-declared copy-constructors. This means that they have no implicitly-generated move-constructor or move-assignment operator. (Therefore your claim "The `e` object is moved" is false; more on this below).

`e` is copyable, `u` is not copyable. `e` is considered *movable* because moving falls back to copying if there is no move-constructor.

---

According to section [except.throw] of C++14  (it was the same in C++11), the initialization of objects when you throw the exception is equivalent to:

```
e temp = e_;      // (1)
const e& _e = temp;  // (2)
```

For (1), no temporary is created, because `e_` and `temp` have the same type.

For (2) it is direct binding: `_e` referes to `temp` directly and there is no temporary again.

---

You may recall that (1) is a [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) context. This means that there must exist an accessible copy or move constructor; but the compiler is allowed to skip the call to that constructor and use the same memory space for both objects.

This is probably what you meant by saying "The `e` object is moved": you saw that it was not copied, but assumed a move when in fact it was copy elision.

---

Putting it all together: the only requirement for the `throw` - `catch` to work is that `e` has a callable move-constructor or copy-constructor. (This constructor may not actually be called, but it must exist).

Your `e` does in fact have a callable copy-constructor, so the code is correct and the MSVC version you tried was bugged.

If you still have access to that version, it would be interesting to try actually writing `e temp = e_; const e& _e = temp;` and see if that code generates the same error message. That would show whether the bug is with the compiler's implementation of *copy-initialization*, as opposed to being a bug with its throwing.

Comment: I've still access to this version of the compiler. The `e temp = e_; const e& _e = temp;` code does compile without error. Attempt to throw any of these variables fails.

Answer (score -1):

MSVC 2013 really requires copyable exception classes. Also, its constructor must be explicit. The following code is incorrect for MSVC 2013:

```
class Ex {
public:
   Ex(){}
private:
   explicit Ex(const Ex&);
};

int main()
{
    throw Ex(); // error
}
```

It seems like you'll not be able to handle this problem in a proper way; any magic with pointers will lead to improper objects deleting.

I only see one solution: notify the framework developers of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was drunk)
I've fixed my sample